# Submit form using one button, one to emailmeform using html script and another to my internal database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, form-submit

Im sorry for my bad english.
Im begineer with PHP and all coding method.
I've been searching this for a days and still cannot find what I need lack to my understanding especially with php, java or ajax.

I have an emailmeform form and I have my own form on 1 php file which I want when client submit the send button, it will save the data entered previously by client to my internal database and send it to emailmeform in the same time but I cannot make this happen.

The solution I think will work is maybe ajax or javascript, but since lack of my knowledge with those codes I cannot solve this issue by my self.

Here's my code (all in 1 php script page):

```js
<?php
session_start();
include "connection/database.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from tb_config");
$config = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
     $username = $_POST['element_1'];
     $password = $_POST['element_2'];
     $referral = $_POST['referral'];
     $a = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * from tb_member where username='$username'"));  
     if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
     echo "<script> alert('Please fill all the required form!!'); </script>";
     } else if (strlen($_POST['element_2']) < 6) { 
     echo "<script> alert('Password at least 6 digit!!!'); </script>";
     } else {
     $save = mysql_query("insert  into tb_member(username,password) values ('$username','$password')");
      exit;
     }
     }
?>
```

```html
<!-- this is emailmeform scipt -->
<form id="emf-form" target="_parent" class="leftLabel" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://www.emailmeform.com/builder/emf/to/ref">
<div id="emf-form-description"><h2>Form Register</h2></div>
</div>
<ul>
<li id="emf-li-0" class="emf-li-field emf-field-text data_container   ">
<label class="emf-label-desc" for="element_0">Your Name</label>
<div class="emf-div-field"><input id="element_0" name="element_0" value="" size="30" type="text"  
    class="validate[optional]"/><div class="emf-div-instruction">Please fill your name</div></div>
<div class="emf-clear"></div>
</li><li id="emf-li-1" class="emf-li-field emf-field-text data_container   ">
<label class="emf-label-desc" for="element_1">Username <span>*</span></label>
<div class="emf-div-field"><input id="username" name="element_1" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['element_1'])) { echo $_POST['element_1']; }  ?>" size="30" type="text" 
    class="validate[required,length[6,15]]"/><div class="emf-div-instruction">At least 6 characters</div></div>
<div class="emf-clear"></div>
</li><li id="emf-li-2" class="emf-li-field emf-field-text data_container   ">
<label class="emf-label-desc" for="element_2">Password <span>*</span></label>
<div class="emf-div-field"><input id="element_2" name="element_2" value="" size="30" type="text"
    emf_mask_input="true"
    class="validate[required,length[6,]]"/><div class="emf-div-instruction">At least 6 characters</div></div>
    <li id="emf-li-post-button" class="middle">
<input  value="Send" type="submit" name="send" onmouseover="return true;"/> 
</li>
</ul>
<input name="element_counts" value="14" type="hidden" />
<input name="embed" value="forms" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

This script works and send to emailmeform, but wont submit any data to my internal database, BUT IF I change the action button to
`<form method="post" action="">`, this will submit to my internal database but not send to emailmeform. I want this work together, submit to my database and send it also to emailmeform.

I have struggling with this and still not found the answer.
Kindly please help.
Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This address http://www.emailmeform.com/builder/emf/to/ref is the same as the current page?

Comment: @ramires.cabral no, this emailmeform.com/builder/emf/to/ref is refer to another page and not on my server, it belong to emailmeform

Comment: So I believe this is your problem: Without this address you perform a post to same page where is the logic to insert to your database. I don't know php profoundly but I guess You have to do a first post to same page and after database insertion another post to this address, but this time on server side. After this line $save = mysql_query("insert...

Comment: The logic is like that, but unfortunately I cannot make the code.
I also think that javascript and ajax will working, I have tried any suggestion that I've found and I still cannot make it, due lack of my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

[Refer this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp), it will demostrate how to insert data in database

Comment: I dont have problem with insert data to database,  the only thing is I want whenever client click on submit button, it will insert the value to my database and send to emailmeform at the same time, basically just like 1 button to do multiple action